# Unable to understand printing array results for awk?

Tags: awk

For a simple `file` which contains:

```
1        a
2        b
3        c
4        d
5        e
6        f
7        g
8        h
9        i
10       j
```

I use that command:

```
awk 'lines[NR]=$0 { print $lines[2]}'
```

It provides me:

```
1        a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
```

How and why? Shouldn't it be that?

```
2 b
```

Also, when I update with following

```
awk '{lines[NR]=$0} END { print lines[2]}' awk.write

2 b
```

with use of  `$`

```
j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `awk`, you access a variable's value by referencing it:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {var=1; print var}'
1
```

There're [special variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_03), which are called field variables, denote by a `$` symbol, followed by a number or an expression. So both `$1` and `$(0+1)` give you the value of the first field.

In your example, you created an associative array `lines`, whose keys are the line number, values are the entire line. To get the value of key `2`, you must use `lines[2]`. With `$lines[2]`, you referred to the nth field, with nth is the value return by `lines[2]`.

When you processed the first line, `lines[2]` is uninitialized, so it may return *0* or *empty* or whatever (the behavior is unspecified by POSIX). In any case, `print` and `print $0` are the same, that's why you got `1        a`, which is `$0` of first line.

From second line, `lines[2]` is assigned by content of the second line, which is `2        b`, and in numeric context, `2        b` return *2*, you got the value of second field `$2` from the second line and so on.

---

Now, since the expression after `$` is not guaranteed to return a numeric result as specified by POSIX:

> Field variables shall be designated by a '$' followed by a number or
>   numerical expression. The effect of the field number expression
>   evaluating to anything other than a non-negative integer is
>   unspecified; uninitialized variables or string values need not be
>   converted to numeric values in this context

So there can be implementations will be broken. At least [Brian Kernighan's own version](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/index.html):

```
$ echo 1 2 | bawk '{print $b}'
bawk: illegal field $(), name "b"
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1
```

In any case, you can force the expression to be evaluated in numeric context, by adding `0` to it:

```
$ echo 1 2 | awk '{print $(b+0)}'
1 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation. So if `lines[2]` gives          
`2        b
2        b
2        b
2        b
2        b
2        b
2        b
2        b`
` $lines[2] ` be nth value taken from results of above. Is that correct?

Comment: `2   b` in numeric context return `2`, so you got `print $2` for the rest of the lines.

Comment: Is there a correction you mentioned `lines[2]` twice in same context.?

Comment: can you please view see the update to my question?

Comment: Can you make it more clear?

Answer (score 2):

You confused `awk`s varibales and workflow. What you probably want is (print only the second line):

```
awk '{lines[NR]=$0} END{print lines[2]}' file
```

But this can be done much simpler by:

```
awk 'NR==2' file
```

---

You command your the question does the following:

```
awk 'lines[NR]=$0 { print $lines[2]}'
```

- `lines[NR]=$0` this is interpreted by `awk` as a condition here. Notice,  `awk` has a workflow that has a mechanism like this (that applies on every line): `'condition{instructions}'`. `lines[NR]=$0` fills the array, but nevertheless it is a condition which is always true. That's why the instructions `{...}` block run for every line.
- `print $lines[2]` That doesn't print the second item of the array, `lines[2]` would. `$lines[2]` expands to a variable whose name is the contents of the second item in the array. For the first line, it's uninitialized, and thus `print` it called without argument. That means it prints the whole line. But when set (in all other lines), it's expanded to `print $2`. That means, print the second field of the line.

Comment: No, there's no variable *b* here, `2        b` in numeric context return only *2*.

Comment: @cuonglm Just tested it and found out, thanks anyway

Comment: And also, for the first line, `lines[2]` is uninitialized, not empty at all. It will be empty when evaluated in string context, and will be `0` when evaluated in numeric context.